# When is it NOT safe to delete an unwanted branch?

Tags: branch, plasticscm

I deleted a branch - then was unable to change back to the main branch under any circumstances. Plastic acted like it wanted that unused branch back and would never allow me to do anything useful with that repository again. To make matters worse, I could not simply undo my delete.

My solution was to start a new repository from scratch. It was a bit painful - but it works again.  And now I know not to go deleting things since there may be dependencies that I don't understand.

So I would appreciate it if anyone can explain to me when it is not safe to delete an unwanted branch.

Answer (score 1):

> I deleted a branch - then was unable to change back to the main branch
>   under any circumstances. Plastic acted like it wanted that unused
>   branch back and would never allow me to do anything useful with that
>   repository again

Do you have any kind of error messages when Plastic was not letting you switch back to the main branch?

> My solution was to start a new repository from scratch. It was a bit
>   painful - but it works again. And now I know not to go deleting things
>   since there may be dependencies that I don't understand.
>
> So I would appreciate it if anyone can explain to me when it is not safe to delete an unwanted branch

Do you still have the original repository?

I would like to request you to write to support at codicesoftware dot com with all the details. We will spend time trying to understand what happened.

The delete branch operation should never break your repository. It's actually a very basic operation that, initially, I don't understand how can impact the repository health, but as I said, contact support to find out the reason. Finally, just in case, let me include why deleting Plastic SCM in Plastic SCM is not needed: http://blog.plasticscm.com/2018/08/why-we-dont-delete-branches-in-plastic.html

Comment: The message was something about the Plastic could not switch branches because there were pending changes.  Oddly, i could find no pending changes anywhere.

Comment: I just went tback to that repository and it is working again! I have no explanation.

Comment: Next time this happens, I will contact tech support before I do anything else.  Part of my problem was that the issue happened on the weekend.  I couldn't wait for tech support to open.

Comment: Here at Plastic we have limited support during the weekend so it's possible to reach us even out of business hours.

Next time please contact us and we will try to guide you to workaround the issue, that also helps us to better understand the scenario.

Comment: Based in your comment I think you saw this message.

https://www.plasticscm.com/documentation/gui/plastic-scm-version-control-gui-guide#CommandsintheBranchesView -> "Switch workspace to this branch"

You can change the switch to branch behavior here: https://www.plasticscm.com/documentation/gui/plastic-scm-version-control-gui-guide#TheOtherOptionsTab